# How can I deploy an Astro project to an Apache web server?

Tags: php, apache, server, build, astrojs

When attempting to deploy my Astro project using **pnpm build**, I encounter the error code:

**[NoAdapterInstalled] Cannot use output: 'server' or output: 'hybrid' without an adapter. Please install and configure the appropriate server adapter for your final deployment.**

The Astro project is configured for production build to be of type 'hybrid' as I need to make API calls that are on the same server. Searching the list of possible adapters on the official Astro website, there doesn't seem to be an option for Apache. Is there a way to bypass installing a server adapter? Or do I need to install an adapter from the list?

I've tried installing Deno and Netlify adapters and then placed the contents of the dist/ folder in the root of your server at /var/www/astro.site/, but still can't see the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Astro is written in JavaScript, not PHP. That means you'll need some kind of JavaScript runtime like Node.js or a [hosted option](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/deploy/).

> as I need to make API calls

Can you do them at build-time? If so, you may still be able to do static site generation instead of the `hybrid` or `server` modes.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to make use of fetch to access a constantly updating database, building the project in static mode is not an option. Since it's the only thing I use hybrid mode for, is there an option to modify the component so that the JavaScript code runs every time it's loaded? If I could use fetch, that would be sufficient.

Comment: Not sure I understand your follow-up question. If you cannot use static site generation, then see https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/server-side-rendering/ But I believe your original question, "can i deploy an Astro project to an Apache" is answered? If so, please accept the answer by clicking the big green check-mark.